# Как вызвать диалог выбора браузера при нажатии на Button

Tags: java, android

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался диалог с выбором браузера и переходил по указанной ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку выполнить вот такой код

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

А лучше всего научиться гуглить такие вещи, это не сложная задача.
Например вот [ссылка](https://www.google.ru/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=android%20open%20url&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6awcV6npNNKDtAGj5ofQDA), где первые несколько ссылок сразу же ответят на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Если вызывать так:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

то, в случае если приложение по умолчанию для ссылок этого типа установлено, диалог с выбором чем открыть не появится.

---

Вот этот же способ принудительно покажет диалог даже если выбора, как такового, нет:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "OPEN WITH:"));
```